# C# expression Lambda

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, lambda

Hi I'm learning about using Lambda from a book. After I copied a piece of code from the book to VS2010 I got the error:

> Delegate '`System.Func<float>`' does not take 1 arguments"

VS2010 marked the error under the left parenthesis at line 3, before "float x". Can you tell me what is wrong?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Func<float> TheFunction = (float x) =>
    {
        const float A = -0.0003f;
        const float B = -0.0024f;
        const float C = 0.02f;
        const float D = 0.09f;
        const float E = -0.5f;
        const float F = 0.3f;
        const float G = 3f;
        return (((((A * x + B) * x + C) * x + D) * x + E) * x + F) * x + G;
    };

    Console.Read();
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're trying to write a function which *accepts* a `float` input, and *returns* a `float` output. That's a `Func<float, float>`. (To give a clearer example, if you wanted a delegate with an `int` parameter and a return type of `float`, that would be a `Func<int, float>`.)

A `Func<float>` would have no parameters, and a return type of `float`. From the documentation of [`Func<TResult>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960):

> Encapsulates a method that has no parameters and returns a value of the type specified by the `TResult` parameter.
>
> ```
> public delegate TResult Func<out TResult>()
> ```

Comment: because you look a little short of rep +1

Comment: @Garry You're voting for the answer, not the book.

Answer (score 4):

Because a `Func<T>` represents a delegate which *returns* a value of type `T`. From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Encapsulates a method that has no parameters and returns a value of the type specified by the *TResult* parameter.

What you want is a `Func<float, float>`—that is, a delegate which accepts a `float` as a parameter *and* returns a value of type `float`.

Answer (score 0):

The final parameter in a Func is the return type, the others are the argument types. For Func with a, b, c as parameters, a and b are the argument types, c is the return type.

```
Func<int, int, double> func = (a,b) => a + b;
int aInt = 1;
int bInt = 2;
double answer = func(aInt, bInt); // answer = 3
```